# how to insert a converted array to mysql? (Php)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have converted a json data to array but now i wanted to insert it into my database i keep getting Array

Here is the code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $checking; $i++) {

  $catid = $ids[$i];
  $catname = $names[$i];
  $catapps = $apps[$i];
  $caturl = $iconurls[$i];

  $query = "INSERT INTO cat VALUES ('".$catid.
  "','".mysql_real_escape_string($catname).
  "','".$catapps.
  "','".mysql_real_escape_string($caturl).
  "')";
  mysql_query($query);
};
```

Comment: No need to mention me in subsequent questions, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it with PDO and prepared statements:

```
try {

  // connect to the DB
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'user', 'password');

  // prepare the query : it will be faster and safer
  $query = $dbh - > prepare("INSERT INTO cat VALUES (id, name, app, url) VALUES (:id, :name, :app, :url)");


  // tell which vars will be used to fill the query
  $query - > bindParam(':id', $catid);
  $query - > bindParam(':name', $catname);
  $query - > bindParam(':app', $catapps);
  $query - > bindParam(':url', $caturl);

  // execute your stuff
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $checking; $i++) {

    $catid = $ids[$i];
    $catname = $names[$i];
    $catapps = $apps[$i];
    $caturl = $iconurls[$i];

    $stmt - > execute();

  };
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // handle connection errors
}

$dbh = NULL;
```

Comment: I disagree with this, as it makes <$checking> trips to the db, instead of one trip if you compose the entire insert in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you to use [AdoDB](http://phplens.com/adodb/) to do a better insert/update data into MySQL. AdoDB do an automatic escaping when you insert/update using `AutoExecute`. Here is an usage example:

```
$catid = $ids[$i];
$catname = $names[$i];
$catapps = $apps[$i];
$caturl = $iconurls[$i];
//set table name
$table_name = 'cat';
//set field values
$data = array (
  'catid' => $catid,
  'catname' => $catname,
  'catapps' => $catapps,
  'caturl' => $caturl
);
//do insert
$result = $adodb->AutoExecute($table_name, $data, 'INSERT');
```

Please note that the key used in `$data` array is the column name in the `cat` table in MySQL, so adjust it according to the column name in your database.

If you want to insert an array into a mysql column, then I suggest you to use `serialize` when inserting, then when fetch the data, use `unserialize` before displaying or processing it.

Answer (score 0):

which column contains `'Array'`? 
try to `print_r` or `var_dump` `$catid`, `$catname`, `$catapps` and `$caturl`.

if you have `'Array'` it's probably because at least one of them is an array. when php try to cast an Array into a String (eg when concaneting it with a string), it's transformed to the string `'Array'`.

Comment: hey there when i use var_dump i get nothing into my database, and when i use print_r i get 1,1,1,1 only

Comment: print_r and var_dump, prints theirs argument. you shouldn't use the return value of print_r or var_dump, it's just for debugging purpose in this case

Answer (score 0):

Compose a single query by concatenating the values.  vis:
(with a bit of reorg for clarity)

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO cat VALUES ";

 for ($i=0; $i<=$checking; $i++) 
 {
    if ($i > 0)
        $query .= ',';
    $catid = intval($ids[$i]);
    $catname = mysql_real_escape_string($names[$i]);
    $catapps = mysql_real_escape_string($apps[$i]);
    $caturl = mysql_real_escape_string($iconurls[$i]);
    $query .= "($catid, '$catname', '$catapps', '$caturl')";
 }
 mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: -1. Suggesting anyone to use mysql_stuff_escape instead of PDO in 2010 is not helping.

Comment: I disagree.  Use of PDO should be an choice, not a religious imperative.
In My defense, I was keeping with the submitters original application, and pointing out a reorganization which leads to clarity.